# Ternary operator in map() react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, operator-keyword, ternary

I made an application in React that shows state holidays using state codes. Now I'm wondering how to handle error when a user types in a non-existent state code or more characters. Here's my try to do it.

```
import React from "react";

const Holidays = props => {
if (props.dataLoaded === false) {
    return null;
  } else {
return (
  <div className="table-responsive">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Holiday</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Type</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {props.country.map((country, index) =>
          country && index === undefined ? (
            <p>{props.error}</p>
          ) : (
            <React.Fragment key={index}>
              <tr>
                <td className="holiday-name">
                  <strong>{country.name}</strong>
                  <br />
                  <p>{country.description}</p>
                </td>
                <td className="holiday-date">
                  {country.date.datetime.day}.{country.date.datetime.month}.
                  {country.date.datetime.year}
                </td>
                <td className="holiday-type">
                  {country.type[0]} {country.type[1]}
                </td>
              </tr>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
          )}
          </tbody>
         </table>
       </div>
      );
    }
      };

 export default Holidays;
```

But with this code when a non-existing state code or more characters is typed in, it throws a error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined".Any help is acceptable

Comment: The error means that `props.country` is `undefined`

Comment: `if (props.dataLoaded === false)` is fairly non-idiomatic, and possibly the problem (if your `props` doesn't have `dataLoaded` at all in the case of the data not [yet?] being loaded). The idiomatic check would be `if (!props.dataLoaded)`.

Comment: Here is in a codepen https://codepen.io/branen890/pen/MxWyXv

Comment: The problem is almost certainly in the *use* of `Holiday`, which you haven't shown. Apparently there is no `country` prop being passed. (And if it's an array, it really should be called `countries`.)

Comment: @branen890 - Please don't hide part of the code off-site. Make sure **all** the necessary code is here, on-site, because A) People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you, and B) Links rot. Please use Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) to provide your runnable example. Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder i didnt know that.I will edit my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue with your code is that your data `props.country` is being mapped before the data is defined, and as we know the map method `.map()` can only be used on arrays. Check [here for more details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Therefore when you try use `map` on something that is `undefined` it will throw that error.

The reason that it is `undefined` at first is in most scenarios because you are fetching the data from the backend either from a server or from some public API. Before the operation of the data that is being fetched is complete your `props.country` will be undefined or whatever you initialize it to.

What you should do is change your current code of:

```
{props.country.map((country, index) =>
          country && index === undefined ? (
            <p>{props.error}</p>
          ) : (
            <React.Fragment key={index}>
              <tr>
                <td className="holiday-name">
                  <strong>{country.name}</strong>
                  <br />
                  <p>{country.description}</p>
                </td>
                <td className="holiday-date">
                  {country.date.datetime.day}.{country.date.datetime.month}.
                  {country.date.datetime.year}
                </td>
                <td className="holiday-type">
                  {country.type[0]} {country.type[1]}
                </td>
              </tr>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
)}
```

To something like below, where we make a check of your `props.country` and make sure that it's loaded - once it is, then try use `map` on it to render out the contents.

```
{props.country ? props.country.map((country, index) =>
          country && index === undefined ? (
            <p>{props.error}</p>
          ) : (
            <React.Fragment key={index}>
              <tr>
                <td className="holiday-name">
                  <strong>{country.name}</strong>
                  <br />
                  <p>{country.description}</p>
                </td>
                <td className="holiday-date">
                  {country.date.datetime.day}.{country.date.datetime.month}.
                  {country.date.datetime.year}
                </td>
                <td className="holiday-type">
                  {country.type[0]} {country.type[1]}
                </td>
              </tr>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
): <div>Data Loading!</div>}
```

So what we are doing here is adding another ternary conditional statement to check `if` `props.country` is `true` THEN apply the `map` method, else you simply return the `div` with contents "Data Loading!" before the data is loaded.

To clarify we are adding `props.country ?` right at the start of your code **inside** the opening curly brace `{` and `: <div>Data Loading!</div>` at the end right **after** the last closing bracket `)` and **before** the closing curly brace `}`.

Now this `<div>Data Loading!</div>` could be anything you don't have to put a div or text you could simply put `null`, but before the data is fetched in those split seconds there will be empty space where your output would be.

Experiment with what you want to put there, but something nice would be to put a loader like a spinner or a styled message to indicate that your data is being fetched.

**Edit**:
You could also initialize your `props.country` to an array, so that using `.map` on it does not resolve into an error automatically even when it's empty. If this was passed down as a props from your parent component's state, simply do:

```
state = {
   country: []
}
```

The prior methods to solving this problem are better, though. But you should still probably get used to initializing your state properties with the data that they will eventually hold.

Comment: @branen890 Accept the answer if you can (tick it on the top left of the answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from "react";

const Holidays = props => {
  return (
    <div className="table-responsive">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Holiday</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Type</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      <tbody>
        {!props.country || props.country.length == 0 ? <p>{props.error}</p> : props.country.map((country, index) =>
            <React.Fragment key={index}>
              <tr>
                <td className="holiday-name">
                  <strong>{country.name}</strong>
                  <br />
                  <p>{country.description}</p>
                </td>
                <td className="holiday-date">
                  {country.date.datetime.day}.{country.date.datetime.month}.
                  {country.date.datetime.year}
                </td>
                <td className="holiday-type">
                  {country.type[0]} {country.type[1]}
                </td>
              </tr>
            </React.Fragment>
          )}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Holidays;
```